# How to get the correct line numbers from `solc --ast-json`?

Tags: solidity, compiler

I have the following in a file:

```
contract Coin {
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);
    function Coin() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

When I apply `solc --ast-json`, the line numbers are all messed up. Say I want to line number of the minter address. It seems every single space is considered a line number, as well as all characters of `contract Coin {`, therefore saying its line number is `20:7:0`!

Any guidance as to how I can get the correct line numbers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @generalpiston in 0xproject's chat page:

The notation is `<character offset>:<length>:<something else>` where everything can be reconstructed that way. 27:7:0 has no line numbers in it!